# Is there a skip parameter in Julia's range?

Tags: python, for-loop, range, julia, skip

In Python, we could iterate using a for-loop and skip the indices using the `skip` parameter as such:

```
max_num, jump = 100, 10
for i in range(0, max_num, jump):
    print (i)
```

I could achieve the same with a while loop by doing this:

```
max_num, jump = 100, 10
i = 0
while i < max_num
    print(i)
    i+=jump
end
```

And using the same `i+=jump` syntax shown below in the for-loop doesn't skip the index:

```
for i in range(0,max_num)
    print(i)
    i+=jump
end
```

**Within a for-loop is "skipping" possible?** If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just do

```
max_num, step = 100, 10

for i in 0:step:max_num
    println(i)
end
```

Using range(), you do not specify max_num, but the desired number of iterations. So `0:step:max_num` equals `range(0, step, max_num/step)`.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is a little bit different in Julia.

It's [`range(start, [step,]length)`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/math/?highlight=range#Base.range) , e.g.

```
for i in range(0, 3, 10)
   println(i)
end
```

[out]:

```
0
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
```

There's another syntax `start:step:max_num`
see @Sayse 's answer for detali

Comment: Ah, it's `range(start, step, end)`.

Answer (score 1):

You do it in your first snipppet (define it in the [`range`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/math/?highlight=range#Base.range)). Aside from that you'd have to use a modulo

```
for i in range(0,max_num):
    if(i % jump != 0):
        continue
    print(i)
```

Comment: Using modulus would be iterating through all `max_num` of cycles, checking the modulo at every iteration, right?

Comment: @NatGillin - Thats correct, its preferred to use the range

Answer (score 1):

`start:jump:end`

Example:

```
a = 0:10:100
```

You can loop using that:

```
for a in 0:10:100
  println(a)
end
```